# setCharAt a for JLabel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I'm trying to replace setCharAt with something that can be used with a JLabel... I've been on oracle doc's looking for a solution. i don't know if I'm looking for the wrong thing or it just doesn't exists.. if it doesn't exists how could i work around that?  i understand my naming convention is off and will be changing them as soon as possible...

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.*;



public class HangmanPanel extends JPanel {
    static Boolean FOUND;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5793357804828609325L;

    public static String answerKey() {
        //get random array element
        String array[] = new String[10];
        array[0] = "hamlet";
        array[1] = "mysts of avalon";
        array[2] = "the iliad";
        array[3] = "tales from edger allan poe";
        array[4] = "the children of hurin";
        array[5] = "the red b" +
                "+adge of courage";
        array[6] = "of mice and men";
        array[7] =  "utopia"; 
        array[8] =  "chariots of the gods";
        array[9] =  "a brief history of time";

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        String s = list.get(0);
        return s;
    }

    public StringBuilder dashReplace(String s) {
        //replace non-white space char with dashes and creates StringBuilder Object
        String tW = s.replaceAll("\\S", "-"); 
        System.out.print(tW + "\n");  
        StringBuilder AnswerKey = new StringBuilder(tW);
        return AnswerKey;
    }
    public static int findAndReplace(String s, JLabel answerKey, String sc,
            char ch) {
        //find position of user input and replace
        int pos = -1;
        FOUND = false;
        while(true){
        pos = s.indexOf(sc, pos+1);
        if(pos < 0){

            break;
        }else{
            FOUND = true;
            //setCharAt dosen't work for JLable
            answerKey.setCharAt(pos, ch);
        }

        }
        JLabel AnswerKey2 = new JLabel(answerKey.toString());
        return pos;
    }




    public HangmanPanel(final String s){
        this.setLayout(null);

        JLabel heading = new JLabel("Welcome to the Hangman App");
        JButton Button = new JButton("Ok");
        //get input

        JLabel tfLable = new JLabel("Please Enter a Letter:");


        final JLabel AnswerKey = new JLabel(dashReplace(answerKey()).toString());

        final JTextField text = new JTextField(10);


        heading.setSize(200, 50);
        tfLable.setSize(150, 50);
        text.setSize(50, 30);
        Button.setSize(60, 20);
        AnswerKey.setSize(200, 100);

        heading.setLocation(300, 10);
        tfLable.setLocation(50, 40);
        text.setLocation(50, 80);
        Button.setLocation(100, 85);
        AnswerKey.setLocation(100,85);

        this.add(heading);
        this.add(tfLable);
        this.add(text);
        this.add(Button);
        this.add(AnswerKey);


        Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // can't access text
                String sc = text.getText();
                char ch = sc.charAt(0);
                findAndReplace(s, AnswerKey, sc, ch);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: `i understand my naming convention is off and will be changing them as soon as possible...` - change them BEFORE posting a question, not after. Make you question as easy as possible for us to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only method available for setting text for `JLabel` components is `setText`. Also `Strings` are immutable. Therefore, you can use `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(answerKey.getText());
builder.setCharAt(pos, ch);
answerKey.setText(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

Why are you trying to use setCharAt(...) with a JLabel. A label is meant to display static text. The only way to change it is to replace the entire string.

I guess you could do something like:

```
StringBuilder text = label.getText();
text.setCharAt(...);
label.setText( text.toString() );
```

Another option would be to use a JTextField that looks like a JLabel:

```
JTextField label = new JTextField(...);
label.setEditable(false);
label.setBorder(null);
label.setOpaque(false);
```

Then when you need to change the text you could do:

```
label.select(...);
label.replaceSelection(...);
```